# How to generate a hyperlink to specific point on page without an id/name?

Tags: html, hyperlink, css-selectors, anchor

#### Scenario/Request

- I would like to send a link to someone, to a website which I don't control / can't change
- As the page is quite long (11 paragraphs), I would like to point users to a specific point on webpage
- However there are **no ID/name attributes in the page**, the content is all made-up of either un-named `<h2>` and `<p>` tags.

#### Scenario/Request

Is there anyway I can generate a link to something like a relative CSS anchor (e.g. the 3rd `<H2>` tag on page, please?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a cross-browser way to do this yet. There have been two proposals in the last decade with unofficial and/or official implementations, of which one is in active development and may soon be available as a cross-browser standard.

The first proposal was [CSS Selectors as Fragment Identifiers](https://www.w3.org/community/cssselfrags), which would have allowed you to use a CSS selector to link to a specific element in the page via a URL fragment:

```
https://example.com/index.html#css(h2:nth-of-type(3))
```

<sup>(This does not actually represent the 3rd `h2` on the page. [It is not possible to write a CSS selector for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524415/matching-the-first-nth-element-of-a-certain-type-in-the-entire-document))</sup>

A [draft](http://simonstl.com/articles/cssFragID.html) was written, some discussions were had (that I was personally involved in), and some [proofs-of-concept in the form of browser extensions](https://shauninman.com/archive/2011/07/25/cssfrag) were made, but it never took off. See also [CSS selector fragment support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799966/css-selector-fragment-support)

The second proposal, and the one currently in active development, is [Text Fragments](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment), which allows you to link to *arbitrary text* in a URL fragment:

```
https://example.com/index.html#:~:text=Example Heading
```

The first implementation was by Google themselves in the form of an extension for [Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-to-text-fragment/pbcodcjpfjdpcineamnnmbkkmkdpajjg) and [Microsoft Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/link-to-text-fragment/pmdldpbcbobaamgkpkghjigngamlolag), but this feature has since actually been shipped in [a number of Chromium-based browsers](https://caniuse.com/url-scroll-to-text-fragment) as of 2020. Try searching for a phrase in your question or my answer.

Comment: Would be good to hear your thoughts on this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68882689/3597276

Comment: @Michael Benjamin: Fairly common question, nothing available or proposed that would help.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I figured, but thought perhaps you knew of something proposed.

Comment: The `#:~:text=` method now (4/2023) works with the current versions of Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge.